# Multiple Words Search in a single PDF with Mac

Tags: software-recommendation, pdf, preview, search

I am looking for any software for Mac (free or not) that is capable to use boolean operator in search (within PDF). To be more precise I would like a software where if I put “apple OR orange OR banana” in search field, I would like to see every occurrence of only the word “apple” and “orange” and “banana” in search results, all together, instead of doing the search for each word. It is similar to the advanced search PDF-XChange Viewer on Windows. Preview app can handle that but it is not reliable. Could you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adobe originally developed the Portable Document Format (PDF). The viewer for these types of documents is a free product called [Adobe Acrobat Reader DC](https://get.adobe.com/reader/). This has an advance search where you can search for the occurrences of "apple" or "orange" or "banana". Below is an illustration of the search window.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I must add for helping others with the same need that I realized that also Preview can handle this quite well, but it does not work properly with "OR" boolean. Use the " | " symbol instead.